# woocommerce custom query string problem in filter widget

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, query-string

I created a widget to add query var to URL to query and filter the instock products in woocommerce shop page, the query string works and return result, but when another filter such as layered navigation or sort (eg based on lower to higher price) is selected, my custom query var (instock query, ?stockstatus=instock) removed from url, and I have to select it again, then both instock and other query strings works.

my custom href tag is in this form `<a class="_widget_click" href="' . esc_url(add_query_arg('stockstatus', 'instock')) . '">Show In Stock Products</a>`

How can I solve this problem? any idea?